# создание динамических библиотек Qt Linux

Tags: qt, qtcreator, dynamic, so

необходимо создать динамическую библиотеку для приложения Trace Mode, когда я создавал в windows в среде Microsoft Visual Studio она автоматически устанавливала зависимости для библиотеки, и все работало нормально, но в Linux нет подобной среды, так вот, какие необходимо прописать зависимости в QtCreator, чтобы библиотека работала? Или что впринципе нужно сделать?

Попробовал создать без  подключения внешних зависимостей, библиотека не запустилась